# How to release an App in the Google Play store without the Android App Bundle feature

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

So, I am trying to upload my first app in the Play Store.
I didn't opt for Google Play App Signing option but I still get the following warning when reviewing my app's release:

## Unoptimized APK

**Warning:**
This APK results in unused code and resources being sent to users. Your app could be smaller if you used the Android App Bundle. By not optimizing your app for device configurations, your app is larger to download and install on users' devices than it needs to be. Larger apps see lower install success rates and take up storage on users' devices.

**Resolution:**
Use the Android App Bundle to automatically optimize for device configurations, or manage it yourself with multiple APKs.

I don't want to use the Android App Bundle so...

- I tried to upload 2 different APKs with the same Version Code, I
  receive an error as such I can't upload same Version Code APKs.
- I uploaded 2 different APKs with different Version Code, I receive a warning as such the APKs with the oldest version codes will be omitted.

So, how the heck should I make this work out. LOL??

Thanks for any advise,

Answer (score 3):

The warning can be ignored. So as long as you don't see any error in red, you can create a release. However, you will need to fill out all required infos for the play store page and your app content first.

I found it quite confusing since on the "releases" page, you don't see any indication that the store page must be filled out first. If you filled out all the information, you will see a checkmark next to this entries in the play console:

[image: Googe play console store entry checkmark]

Comment: Oh! I had to fill out those sections... Alrighty, problem solved. Thank you, sir!